# Android - force full screen soft keyboard

Tags: android

Is there any way I can force soft keyboard to appear in full screen mode, so that there are only 2 items on the screen:

1. Text content
2. Keyboard

?

Android 2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for *fullscreen* or *extract* mode

[Link to Android documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

**EDIT** I forgot to mention this

> The final major mode is fullscreen or extract mode. This is used when
>   the IME is too large to reasonably share space with the underlying
>   application. With the standard IMEs, you will only encounter this
>   situation when the screen is in a landscape orientation, although
>   other IMEs are free to use it whenever they desire

As I understand there's no way to do such a thing so that it works consistently across all devices and soft keyboards (well, unless you implement your own but I think this would be very out of scope)

Comment: The problem is, I do have enough space on my screen so it always appears below. I need it to switch to extract mode.

Comment: I edited my answer. I think this can't be done considered the high number of screen sizes and soft keyboards available